# How to dynamically add text fields to a form based on a number the user puts in

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to make a form that asks the user for a number of units, then asks whether or not they would like those units to be provisioned, and depending on the answer, generates text fields corresponding with the number of units the typed in, along with a text field asking for an account number.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">

</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

function Getunits(value) {
var units = document.getElementById('units');
for(count=0; count<=units; count++) {
$("<input type='text'>").appendTo("inpane");
 }
document.getElementByTag('futureacc').InnerHTML='What is your account number? <input type="text" value="accountnum">';

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
<form method="post" action="sendcontact.php">
<div id="unitammount" class="inpane">
Number of units ordered: <input type="text" name="units" id="units"/><br />
</div>

<div id="futureacc" class="inpane">
Are these units to be provisioned? <input type="radio" name="select" value="yes" onClick="Getunits('units.value')"/> Yes <input type="radio" name="select" value="no"/> No
</div>
```

Obviously I would like the new text fields to appear inside the futureacc div and inpane div respectively.

I don't know whether it's the loop that doesn't do anything or that I'm not appending correctly but as I currently have it this does nothing...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a number of errors with your code.  It was confusing because you were mixing jQuery and pure Javascript.  It's generally better to just use jQuery if you've decided to use it anyway.  Your loop should have been iterating while it was smaller than `units.val()`, not while it was smaller than or equal to `units`.  `innerHTML` is spelled with a lowercase "i," and your `appendTo` selector needed a period before the class name.  I went ahead and cleaned up your code so it should work now!

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <form method="post" action="sendcontact.php">
        <div id="unitammount" class="inpane">
              Number of units ordered: <input type="text" name="units" id="units"/>
        </div><br>

        <div id="futureacc" class="inpane">
            Are these units to be provisioned? <input type="radio" name="select" value="yes" onClick="getUnits()"/> Yes <input type="radio" name="select" value="no"/> No <br>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>​
```

Javascript:

```
function getUnits() {
    var units = $("#units").val();
    for (var count = 0; count < units; count++) {
        $("<input type='text' /><br>").appendTo("#futureacc");
    }
    $("#futureacc").append('<br>What is your account number? <input type="text" placeholder="accountnum">');
}​
```

## [**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/JL4VB/)

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much for this. I'm incredibly new to js and programming in general and this little side project might have been a bit above what I can presently handle, but again, thank you so much for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
var units = document.getElementById('units');
```

needs to be

```
var units = document.getElementById('units').value;
```

you are passing value to onclick but it is a string will not give you exact value anyway you are not using it in you function so it doesnt have any side effect.

also you need to some error check to make sure that user has entered a number

with

```
for(count=0; count<=units; count++)
```

You are adding 1 more text box than user entered value. so if user has entered 4 you are creating 5  <= should be changed to <

Comment: Thank you, I've fixed those two flubs.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong

```
onClick="Getunits('units.value')"
```

Instead use this:

```
onClick="Getunits(units.value)"
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[name=select]').click(function(){
    if($(this).val() ==='yes'){
        var numberOfTextboxes = $('#units').val();
        for(var i =0; i<numberOfTextboxes; i++){
            $('#unitammount').append('<input type="text" />');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E4cNb/)